# Issue with Mysqli Query Result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make a login form using mysqli method.I am not getting any error but in both case (Correct or Incorrect Authentication) I am getting the second part of the IF condition result! **"You are not allowed!."**

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$eMail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["eMail"]);
$passWord = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["psword"]);
$query  = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE (email='$eMail' AND pass='$passWord')";
if( $query > 0 ) {
echo "You are allowed.";
}
else{
echo "You are not allowed!.";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I also changed to if condition to following

```
if( $mysqli->query > 0 ){}
```

I have a table called users and two columns(email, pass) containing users Email and Password.Now can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Is this your complete code? If so, you are missing a lot of steps. Not to mention, mixing and matching MySQL libraries.

Comment: Hi Jason what do you mean bu complete code? if you mean the HTML and connect to database part I already have them in seperate files as include_once('db.php') and login.index can you please let me know what exactly you mean?

Comment: The `$query` in your code is a string, not a query or result. You have to query using the mysqli object, for example: `$db->query($query)`. Please check out the examples [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: If one of the answers below is correct, please mark it as so, otherwise stack overflow will never know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote questions somewhat useful so other users with similar questions can find answers with more ease.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you are using mysql and mysqli functions. This should be updated. This is also off the assumption that your variable `$mysqli` contains a valid mysqli database connection:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$eMail = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST["eMail"]);
$passWord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST["psword"]);
$query  = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE (email='$eMail' AND pass='$passWord') LIMIT 1");
if( $mysqli->num_rows($query) > 0 ) {
    echo "You are allowed.";
}else{
    echo "You are not allowed!.";
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
$mysqli->close();?>
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, I used your code and I am not getting anything now. it is just an empty page

Answer (score 1):

The use of the mysql_* extensions has been discouraged in favor of `mysqli` and/or `pdo` functions.

Your code is failing because there's no calling of the `mysql_query` function, so in this line of your code:

```
$query > 0
```

All you are doing is verifying if your String is greater than 0 and that's why you are always getting a false result.

I've made an adaptation from my object oriented login method to a (most of) procedural one.

Look below for a different approach on handling user input by binding parameters to a prepared statement:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli){
    if($login_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Pass,Salt from Users WHERE Email = ? LIMIT 1")){
        $login_stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
        //The line above prevents SQL Injection
        $login_stmt->execute();
        $login_stmt->store_result();

        $rows = $login_stmt->num_rows;

        $login_stmt->bind_result($db_pass,$salt); //Stores the result in the $db_pass and $salt variables
        $login_stmt->fetch();
        $password = hash('sha512',$password.$salt); //This is a method I'm using to encrypt using sha512 encription
        if($rows==1){//The user exists
            if($db_pass==$password){
            //User logged in, do your stuff here
                return true;
            } else { 
                //password not correct
                return false;
            }
        } else{
            return false; //no user
        }
     } else {
         //Prepared statement failed
         return false;
    }
}
```

The main difference here is how the prepared statement alongside with `bind_param` will prevent SQL Injections on your code.

I hope it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to run your query. See [`mysql_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: Hi John, I am using mysqli library do I still need to run the mysql_query() method?

Comment: Your code shows that you are using the old mysql_* functions. The mysqli function all start with mysqli (when used in procedural format). And, yes, you still need to call either mysql_query() or mysqli_query() to actually execute your sql.

Answer (score 0):

firstly connect to the database then execute the query using `mysql_query($query);`

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: Hi vlcekmi3, I am using mysqli library do I still need to run the mysql_query() method